# How to connect four computers together without using any external device?

Tags: networking, ethernet, iptables, routing, syslinux

I need to connect four computers serially. The topology is given below.

```
                c1<--->c2<--->c3<--->c4
```

I have multiple ethernet cards in c2 and c3 computers. I don't need any external connectivity from the internet, just these four computers should be able to communicate with each other.

Note: all the computers are running Ubuntu version greater than equal to 16.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this homework for some class?

Comment: http://opensourceforu.com/2015/04/how-to-configure-ubuntu-as-a-router/

Comment: No, I want to create a network test bed. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that your network cards support both straight and crossover cable. If not you will need  crossover Ethernet cables.

Then, once all the devices are connected :

**Enable forwarding**

First activate the IPv4 forwarding on your devices.

To enable it on the fly you can use :

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

To enable it permantly, edit the file `/etc/sysctl.confand` uncomment the line with net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1. Then reload the conf : `sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`.

**Define IP and Routes**

Then, configure the IP and routes of your devices.

To perform that you can edit directly the file /etc/network/interfaces.

Example :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.1 # c1, configure the same subnet in the c2 interface that is connected to the c1 device
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        up route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

If all of your devices are in the same subnet, you does not need to describre routes.

**Debug/Confirm**

If this does not work, check the Firewall and edit it if required :

```
sudo iptables -L
```

Hope this answer help.

**Edit**

Since C2 is directly connected to both subnetworks you just have to set a route to the third network.

You can specify multiple interfaces in */etc/network/intefaces*

```
auto  [interface1]
iface [interface1] inet static
        address 192.168.1.2 # The same subnet that is configure for C1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        # You don't need specific route for this interface because there is no another network behind C1

auto [interface2]
iface [interface2] inet static
        address 192.168.2.1 # C2<--->C3 subnet
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        up route add -net 192.168.3.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.2 # Where 192.168.3.0 is the C3<-->C4 subnet and 192.168.2.2 the C3 address of the interface in the subnet C2<-->C3
```

I did not test this configuration but this should work. Once you finish to configure you can check the routes with `ip route` command.

C3 and C2 have direct route to both network. So you just have to define a route to the third network (C3 <--> C4 for C2 and C1 <--> C2 for C3). Once C2 and C3 have access to all network, you just have to defined them as default gateway for C1 and C4.

[image]

Comment: I have a query.

By referring the above network topology I can able to set the interface file for c1 and c4. But c2 and c3 has two interface cards, so I need to define two entries in interface file, so should I define two different gw for both entries.

If possible could you please give an example for either c2 or c3 as well.

Comment: Please check the edit of my answer.

Comment: Thanks for giving such in-depth explanation. 
I have done the configuration as per your suggestion and my network component get IP address.

Comment: All computers are able to ping each other.

Comment: I'm glad that's work. You can define my answers as accepted if you think that make the work and to close this thread.

Comment: Just need a quick confirmation about multiple gateways in a single machine.
Let say if above topology has five nodes serially, then do we need to add two gateways in middle node or just defining an extra route is fine.

Comment: A gateway is a device that allow you to communicate with devices that are not in your subnetwork. When you add a default route and try to reach any IP that are not in your subnetwork your computer will use this default route and the gateway (router, ISP Box, server...) will forward and perform the communication. But for that the gateway have to know how to reach the IP that you want to communicate with. So you can configure specific route (another gateway) for specific prefix.
`sudo ip route add 10.10.10.0/24 via 192.168.1.254`  --> Will use 192.168.1.254 gateway to reach 10.10.10.0/24.

Comment: But configure static routes when you get too much devices can be a real pain. That's why protocol like OSPF, ISIS, RIP (and BGP for ISP) exists. You can configure it on Ubuntu but this is out of scope here.